# force using Basic display driver?

Tags: windows, drivers, display

How can I prevent Windows 8.1 from automaticaly instaling Intel HD graphics driver?
Or rather to force using Basic display driver?

My graphics card is deffective (display blinks frequently when driver installed), so I want to use Basic display driver (blinking issue doesn't happen) but Windows always installs Intel HD driver automatically. I have turned off automatic driver instalation in "device instalation settings" and automatic maintenence but it somehow still installs Intel driver...

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Grab Hardware Id from device manager > graphic adapter > properties > Details tab, and select Hardware Ids from the drop-down menu under Property.

Using one of the values in the next step should be enough but I've used em all.

Open Group Policy Editor
(start > run > gpedit.msc)
go to 
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Installation > Device Installation Restrictions. 
open setting 
"Prevent installation of devices that match any of these device IDs."

click enable
click show
add respective Hardware Ids you grabbed from device manager.
Apply.

Profit.

Hope this helps.

P.S.
If you are running Win10
you can try this as well:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3073930/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-driver-update-from-reinstalling-in-windows-10

Comment: Have you personally verified this procedure works on Windows 8.1?

Comment: On Windows 10 and 8.1. But since we are talking about damaged hardware your mileage may vary. 
For me it worked on several occasions (lotsa old hardware at the firm I work for)

Comment: Tried it out, it helped work around a dying laptop video card.

Comment: Does not work for Win10 home - even if you force-enable the Group policy editor, those directories (system/device etc) are missing from it.